react| react-router-dom проблема с Link
Хочу сделать линки, которые не перезагружают сайт во время перехода:
{
Link
} -> "react-router-dom";

Получаю в результате чисто белый экран. Когда убираю <Link to="profile">Профіль</Link>, все восстанавливается.
Полный код можете посмотреть тут: https://github.com/harttman/tele-cord

Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе

В какой момент появляется чисто белый екран? При переходе по ссылке? или при первом открытии страницы? Есть ли ошибки в консоли?

У меня это находиться в компоненте NavBar, когда не убираю и его с App все работает! А когда добавляю в App снова белый екран, оно не рендериться. Я Ожидал что у меня будут ссылки по которым можно будет перейти

Ну тобишь:  с profile, помещаю в App белый екран, убираю  все снова работает

а зачем тебе два  компонента BrowserRouter? один в App, второй в main?

Проверял, вдруг проблема в том, что Линк наxодится вне BrowserRouter
